# Creating an activity log

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm pretty new to Android development, but I'm trying to create a log of all user activity, one that has to be a highly customizeable csv format. I'm wondering if anyone can give me some guidance.

I may be being super inefficient right now, but I currently just have a "logEvent" function that I call each time anything gets clicked or selected or input that builds a comma-separated string that appends to a giant log string that gets passed to the different activities. I can view this giant log string and it looks just like how I want it, but I'm trying to figure out how to save it to a file on phone.

I was checking out the docs, but I'm not sure which option I should be looking at.

I need the log file to be viewable, and ideally share-able, but not editable. I want to be able to retain maybe up to 100 logs or something like that. Each file would log activity from open until exit of the application.

TIA

Comment: What's the ultimate question here? How to write to a file?

Comment: i think it would be enough to use firebase analytics

Comment: You can either use Firebase analytics to get a detailed log or you can create a local file in resources directory and write the info to that. But a better approach is Firebase logging.